# export dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
file = {"Formations" : ["some1","some2","some3"], "Depth": [1,2,3] }
```

I want "Formation" and "Depth" to be the header, and want the file to be listed vertically in my output csv file. So,

```
Formations       Depth
  some1            1 
  some2            2
  some3            3
```

something like this.

How can this be done? Its ok that I convert depth list [1,2,3] into a string list, like ["1", "2", "3"], if thats necessary.

---

To COLDSPEED, this is how it looks like in the output file.

```
Formations           Depth
  (blank)           (blank) 
   some1               1
  (blank)           (blank)
   some2               2
  (blank)           (blank)
   some3               3
```

(blank) here just denotes empty line with nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a `DictWriter`, but it would be easier to just call `zip` and then write each pair to your CSV.

```
import csv

file = {"Formations" : ["some1","some2","some3"], "Depth": [1,2,3] }

with open(...) as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for x, y in zip(file['Formations'], file['Depth']):
        w.writerow([x, y])
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late accept. I used your code, and I was able to export it to csv file, but when I opened the csv file in Excel, it created an empty line between each lines. I edited the post so that you can see how it is

Comment: @EricKim Check your column values? If not, just call `str.strip` on all string values before printing.